# EXT4 md raid show negative value in df -h, fsck failing

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, fsck

I have md raid ext4 with 20 devices, All the devices are in good condition.
now, when ever I do `df -h` I see a negative value under 'Available'.

I tried to remount the raid with `umount` & `mount` but it didn't help.

I was told to run `fsck.ext4 /dev/md0` but I get error message:
`Filesystem has unsupported features, get newer fsck version.`

so I installed e2fsprogs-1.43.1
and when I run `./e2fsck /dev/md0` I get tons of errors:

```
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 696 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 466 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 470 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 568 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 614 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 2382364674 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
BackUp: Inode 222789841 block 3531604892 conflicts with critical metadata, skipping block checks.
```

at the end it says it failed.

```
BackUp: Inode 222789841 is too big.

BackUp: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
```

Comment: RAID has no direct role in the problem, if the array looks okay in /proc/mdstat, then it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

`UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY` means there is some file system error in the disk. Run the `fsck` command manually. After that it will ask  some more questions - just answer `y` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> and finally reboot the system. [Source.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: Actually, do read the question before pressing `y`. fsck might ask you a question which will render some data inaccessible or even gone, know what you're doing when approving changes to the filesystem. Doing a backup if you haven't done already is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

You had to run a manual `fsck`.

Please note that this operation should be done with the filesystem unmounted, so if it your root filesystem which need checking, the easiest way is to issue `touch /forcefsck` and to reboot the system.

Regards.